# Travis CI: Avoiding repeated installation of packages for each commit

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

As you can see in [this travis.yml](https://github.com/pranavkantgaur/CDTGenerator/blob/master/.travis.yml) file, my code is dependent on some third party libraries for which I am installing them on remote system before building the project.

Travis downloads and builds these libraries every time I push a commit, can this be avoided? I mean, to do it only once for a project and then later build process uses those already built libraries for subsequent commits?

Answer (score 4):

There is a feature of [caching directories and dependencies](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#Caching-directories-%28Bundler%2C-dependencies%29) but it is currently experimental and not available for public repositories directly. To add this support for public repositories we have to disable sudoing by adding `sudo: false` to the top level of `.travis.yml`. This will route the future builds to [*container-based infrastructure*](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/) of Travis CI.

But the way caching works right now it has limitations, quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#How-does-the-caching-work%3F):

> The caching tars up all the directories listed in the configuration and uploads them to S3, using a secure and protected URL, ensuring security and privacy of the uploaded archives.
>   Note that this makes our cache not network-local, it’s still bound to network bandwidth and DNS resolutions for S3. That impacts what you can and should store in the cache. If you store archives larger than a few hundred megabytes in the cache, it’s unlikely that you’ll see a big speed improvement.